# Emacs: GUI with emacs --daemon not loading fonts correctly

Tags: emacs, fonts, daemon

I set up an `emacs --daemon` in order to startup emacs faster. I like especially the GUI version of emacs, so I do `emacsclient -c` to open a new emacs frame.

The problem is that I have changed my fonts, but these fonts aren't loaded if I start `emacsclient -c`. However, they are applied if I start just `emacs` (but this causes the whole `.emacs` to be evaluated).

So: Is there a way of applying my font settings also if I start emacs with `emacsclient -c`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In short, you have to use `default-frame-alist` for that. Like this:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Inconsolata-dz-15")))
```

This will be evaluated every time you start a new, graphical frame in Emacs. This is also where you save other frame-related settings, like settings for your `fringe` and such.

Comment: Thank you. That pointed to the right direction and let me fix the problem.

Comment: This works fine but I have side effect, the rest of my configuration including (tool-bar-mode -1) is not loaded with emacsclient -c so I fix the font problem but I load a frame with default options, any idea?

Comment: Strange. Try setting `(tool-bar-mode 0)` instead of -1. That's what I do, and it works for *NIX and OS X. But I've included this for windows (in `default-frame-alist`), not sure if it works (I don't use Windows more than necessary): `(tool-bar-lines . 0)`

Comment: @jrbalderrama try using `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist ...)` instead of '(setq default-frame-alist ...)`. This works fine for me and shouldn't overwrite your `default-frame-list` so you can keep your customizations.

Answer (score 12):

The following will probably do what you are looking for.

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Inconsolata-12"))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Emacs 23.2 changing the monospaced font in GNOME will change the Emacs font as well. In earlier edition you'll have to do this:

```
echo "Emacs.font: Monospace-10" >> ~/.Xresources
xrdb
```

Replace Monospace-10 with the actual font you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

`emacslient` has an option `-F` (`--frame-parameters`) that lets you specify the font of a newly-created frame

Example:

```
emacsclient -c -F '((font . "8x16"))'  some_file
```