# Using a list of fonts with a daemonized Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

My GNU Emacs configuration is shared between multiple computers (including fixed installations for FreeBSD, Ubuntu, and Windows 7 and a portable installation with NT Emacs and Cygwin on a USB drive). I want to define a list of fonts that Emacs will try, in order, until an installed font is found (since I don't always have root access where I can install fonts). Usually, `set-fontset-font` and friends would work; however, when Emacs is used as a daemon (`emacs --daemon`) the normal fontsets aren't created until a frame is opened. Since this all needs to run as part of my `.emacs`, that's too late.

(Just in case the fontset creation problem is something specific to FreeBSD's Emacs port or my configuration, [this is the output of make showconfig](http://pastebin.com/wAdJhSpL).)

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984730/emacs-gui-with-emacs-daemon-not-loading-fonts-correctly) got me most of the way there; the proposed answer works as long as you only need one font. To have multiple fallback fonts, you need to define a fontset and tell Emacs to use that fontset for frames. First, define the list of fonts you want to use:

```
;; Fill in your list of fonts here
(setq my-fonts '("-xos4-terminus-medium-*-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1" ...))
```

Then, put those fonts into the standard fontset:

```
;; NOTE: only works if you don't use --daemon
(dolist (font (reverse my-fonts))
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-standard" 'unicode font nil 'prepend))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "fontset-standard"))
```

This will work fine as long as you never start Emacs as a daemon; if you do, you're told

```
error: Fontset `fontset-standard' does not exist
```

To fix that, we need to create the standard fontset before adding fonts to it. Emacs defines `standard-fontset-spec` to be the value the standard fontset is initialized with; we can do it ourselves by calling `create-fontset-from-fontset-spec` first:

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec standard-fontset-spec) ;to make --daemon work
(dolist (font (reverse my-fonts))
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-standard" 'unicode font nil 'prepend))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "fontset-standard"))
```